# How to Parse SAML 2.0 Response without using OpenSAML Jar

Tags: xml, saml, saml-2.0, opensaml

It is not a question rather this is a findings I want to share I struggled a bit in last month while replacing the logic to parse a SAML 2.0 Response without using OpenSAML library

Here we need to decode and inflate the SAML Response. The Namespace will be same so this can be used for all the SAML Response parsing.

I used DOM parser. This Code is just to take pick up the username. Same method can be used to read the signature and parse the signature as well Which I will show in a different article.

```
    private String decodeSAMLResponseUserIdandSession(String samlEncoded,
        String type) throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException,
        SAXException {
    byte[] decodedValue = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(samlEncoded);
    String tmlXml = new String(decodedValue, "utf-8");

    if (!tmlXml.contains(":Response")) {
        System.out.println("Inside the Unzip");
        decodedValue = inflateValue(decodedValue);
    }
    String tmlXml2 = new String(decodedValue, "utf-8");

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    StringReader strreader = new StringReader(tmlXml2);
    InputSource isstream = new InputSource(strreader);
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(isstream);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion", "Subject");

    System.out.println("----------------------------");

    for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

        Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element eElement1 = (Element) nNode;

                System.out.println("First Name : "
                        + eElement1.getElementsByTagNameNS("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion", "NameID").item(0).getTextContent().toLowerCase());


            }


    }


}

    private static byte[] inflateValue(byte[] decodedValue) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedValue);
    Inflater unzipper = new Inflater(true);
    InflaterInputStream zipStream = new InflaterInputStream(bis, unzipper);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int read = zipStream.read(buf);
    while (read > 0) {
        bos.write(buf, 0, read);
        read = zipStream.read(buf);
    }
    zipStream.close();
    bos.close();
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you choose to do this, rather than use a trusted and maintained package? It seems foolish to choose to DIY SAML handling.

Comment: To avoid this https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/2253462_1.html#FIX I did not have an option to change the prefer-web-inf classes in the EAR because that EAR comes from third party and I do not have an authority to change that just to make my SAML plugin code work.    as well as, Weblogic admin did not allow it to delete the openSaml inside weblogic modules.

Comment: Ugh. That sounds like a nightmare. So helpful of Oracle to break things... Sounds like it may be worthwhile to look at another middleware provider... Writing DIY code that parses SAML responses correctly is certainly possible, but the signature processing gets even crazier. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in using the OpenSAML library because the Oracle issue points out that there were several versions of OpenSAML being used there such as: 2.0.0 and 3.0.0. So, as long as you stick with one version there would be no problem in using the opensaml jar. Hope this helps you.